# C++ Output file

Tags: c++

so i'm trying to make a program which asks questions and i answer them until i choose to stop (its inside a loop).
So for instance if i open the file it should look something like this:

```
test.txt
First question: 1.
Second Question: 2.
loop
First question: 3.
Second question: 4.
loop
...
```

but i'm getting only the last input i made.

```
do {
cout<<"Enter 0 to end. \n";
cin >> a;

ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("test.txt");
myfile << "First question: \n";
cin >> a;
myfile << a;
myfile << "Second question: \n";
cin >> b;
myfile << b;

myfile.close();
}while (a!=0);
```

Comment: Why are you opening and closing the file in the loop? Get that code out of the loop. You could also set the open mode to append if you wanted.

Comment: I want to keep entering data until i decide to stop.

Comment: Many similar questions already.  Search the internet for "stackoverflow c++ file question answer".

Comment: Once a file is opened, you don't need to keep opening it.  BTW, you user's won't see the prompt, so there is a mysterious input from the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest copying the question and answers to the file.

```
int main(void)
{
  bool can_continue = true;
  ofstream myfile("test.txt");
  while (can_continue)
  {
    std::string question;
    std::cout << "First Question:\n";
    std::getline(cin, question);
    my_file << "First Question:\n";
    my_file << question << "\n";

    std::cout << "Second Question:\n";
    std::getline(cin, question);
    my_file << "Second Question:\n";
    my_file << question << "\n";

    std::cout << "\nEnter 0 to quit, any other number to continue:";
    int number;
    std::cin >> number;
    if (number != 0)
    {
      can_continue = false;
    }
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

By copying the prompt to the terminal, your Users can tell if there will be an input coming up.

Be aware that using `operator>>` with a `std::string` results in only a word read in.  You will want to use `std::getline` to input text until the Enter is pressed.

Comment: I'm not yet good enough to understand the continue, and the code doesn't work in that matter.

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  The `continue` is a reserved word.  See my edits.

Comment: EXIT_SUCCESS was not declared in this scope, so i replaced it with return 0; the code is then working i can enter and press 0, but there is no data in test.txt

Answer (score 0):

std::ofstream::open does not append by default. Thus, in your case it will just make a file with two inputs for each loop iteration and overwrite it the next.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that every time your loop runs, you get a fresh pointer to your file and you start overwriting what is already there.

There are 2 ways you can fix this.

1) The one I strongly suggest, take the following three statements outside your loop. The first two before the loop and the last one after the loop. This will still give you the option to write as many times as you want.

```
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("test.txt");

myfile.close();
```

2) Open the file in append mode. To do this replace

```
myfile.open("test.txt");
```

with

```
myfile.open("test.txt", std::ios_base::app);
```